# How to send only a page of website to default browser and load rest of the website pages in webview?

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm working on webview in android studio where I need to load a website but I also don't want to load some specific pages of that website in webview. 
Let's assume I load `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/` in my webview but I want to send `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` this url to default browser whenever user wants to visit this url.

for doing this, I've tried this code in my `webViewClient()` but it doesn't work!

```
 @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.contains("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")){
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: looks good? What's your question?

Comment: I'm loading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ url in my webview and now I want to send user to default browser if the url changes to ….com/questions/ask pages.. before I was loading only com.questions/ page and if the url extends to com.questions/ask page I want to send user to default browser. I hope you get it now

Comment: I got what you *want* to do in the first place. What I *meant* was: Your code looks good and should work. What is your specific problem with it? Provide Logs or stacktraces. Otherwise no one is able to help

Comment: what's wrong with your this code? It looks good. Have you tried it?

Comment: try  equals  if(!url.equals("https://stackoverflow.com/questions"))  this will result all url redirected default browser except "https://stackoverflow.com/questions"

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko He wrote he tried it.

Comment: @GeorgePJ wont work, as it doesn't catch ie. `http(s)://stackoverflow....`

Comment: @Rafael He can change that to what ever need to be matched.

Comment: the problem is it can't detect the questions/ask page in shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url); method and it doesn't throw any error.

Comment: @GeorgePJ actually I don't want to redirect all pages of stackoverflow to default browser but only one specific page that should be open in default browser is stackoverflow.questions/ask this page.... the ''ask'' page!

Comment: @RafaelT, I know that, but as I said - he didn't say what is wrong.

Comment: try debugging. Check step by step which parameters you get in your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, and why it does not behave as you want.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comments: If the Problem is, that this method never triggers I suspect the URL to be in another form than you expect it to be.

Try logging passed URL's like this:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Log.i("WebView", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading called with URL=" + url);
    if(url.contains("questions/ask")){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I suspect that there isn't a `https` but a `http` in front or that is is omitted completely or just a relative path to the one were you are (i.e. just "questions/ask")

Comment: I'm sorry...it doesn't work at my end! anyway, thank you so much for your effort!

Comment: So if it doesn't work would you mind making the Logs available??

Comment: If log result isn't showing, I guess your method is never called and thus having no effect! Have you properly set the `WebViewClient`? Have you seen the disclaimer?                                         **This method was deprecated in API level 24.
Use shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, WebResourceRequest) instead.**? Which API level yre you testing with?